# What is a word or phrase that can be used to refer to media entities like TV programs, newspaper articles, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or a short phrase that can be used as a collective term for different "units" of media: term that encompasses most if not all of the following:

- TV programs, talk shows, etc. from *electronic media*
- Channels, profiles, pages, and posts from *social media*
- Articles, news reports, and op-ed pieces from *print media*

Comment: Is it mass-communication that you are looking for?

Comment: Why not simply *media*? It occurs in all three of your bulleted items and, as such, is the most obvious collective term. Am I missing something?

Comment: For some of the things listed here, it is not entirely clear what constitutes a 'unit'. For example, is a television series a unit, in the relevant sense, or particular episode of it?

Comment: @RamPillai I have thought about mass communication but I'm under the impression that it refers to the _act_ of imparting information rather than the _units_ or _pieces_ that are used to convey said information. Am I not correct in this assumption?

Comment: @jsw29 By unit, I mean a general and encompassing entity like _talk show_. It doesn't necessarily refer to any specific episode or even a particular talk show, but the fact that it is a form of _media_ that can communicate information to its consumer. I think the word _program_ comes really close to what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it doesn't cover the printed material.

Comment: @UzairA., OK, but if the question is really about the **types** of what appears in the media (rather than the particular instances of these types), then both *unit* and *entity* are misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, why not **media**? From Lexico:

> **[media](https://www.lexico.com/definition/media)**: (the media) *[treated as singular or plural]* The main means of mass communication (broadcasting, publishing, and the internet) regarded *collectively*.

This collective term (note that the definition uses the word *collectively*) covers all three of your bulleted items, each of which involves an adjective modifying **media**.

If you'd prefer and alternative to **media**, you could us *mass communications*, as indicated in the definition of **media** and suggested by Ram Pillai.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks. The OP seems to be looking for a collective term that includes the *units* listed in the bullets. Why is that collective term not **media** as per the OP’s own use of the word and its Lexico definition?

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks again. You may be right. Let’s see if the OP clarifies. If you’re right, then I’d probably go with mass communications.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough -- English is not my first language and I'm at a loss for how to exactly phrase what I'm looking for. By collective, I only meant a word that can encompass as many of the intended entities as possible. These comments have helped me to reflect on my own requirement and I think the word _media_ itself will do the trick.

Comment: @UzairA. Your English was fine. It’s harder to pose an unambiguous question than one might think.